# How to sum a variable by group but do not aggregate the data frame in R?

Tags: r, sum, grouping

although I have found a lot of ways to calculate the sum of a variable by group, all the approaches end up creating a new data set which aggregates the double cases.

To be more precise, if I have a data frame:

```
 id  year    
 1   2010
 1   2015
 1   2017
 2   2011
 2   2017
 3   2015
```

and I want to count the number of times I have the same ID by the different years, there are a lot of ways (using aggregate, tapply, dplyr, sqldf etc) which use a "group by" kind of functionality that in the end will give something like:

```
 id   count
 1      3
 2      2
 3      1
```

I haven't managed to find a way to calculate the same thing but keep my original data frame, in order to obtain:

```
 id  year   count  
 1   2010     3
 1   2015     3
 1   2017     3
 2   2011     2
 2   2017     2
 3   2015     1
```

and therefore do not aggregate my double cases. 
Has somebody already figured out?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `dplyr --> mutate`, `data.table --> :=`, `baseR --> ave`

Comment: In `dplyr`, you can use `df %>%
  add_count(id)` or `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(count = n())`.

Comment: 1st use `rle` function (or others) to calculate your second table. 2nd merge the first and the second tables by the 'id' column to get the third table

Comment: did u got the solution?

Comment: @sai saran  yes, thanks to tmfmnk i did the follow using dplyr : 

     df %>%
     add_count(id)%>%
     group_by(id, year)

Thank you all